# Telling Resharper to ignore lib folder in node_modules

Tags: typescript, resharper, node-modules, typescript-typings

Here we go again, another month and another Resharper Update which seems to break everything in TypeScript when working with Node Modules and @types

I am working with TypeScript, React and Redux, so have various ReduxActions strongly typed using the npm package `redux-actions` and `@types/redux-actions`

My code looks like:

```
const pageReducer = handleActions<IPageState, number | string>({

     [actionTypes.doSomething]: (state: IPageState, action: Action<string>): IPageState => {    
        // some code to manipulate the state
        return {}; // returning the manipulated state
    },

    [actionTypes.doSomethingElse]: (state: IPageState, action: Action<number>): IPageState => {    
        // some code to manipulate the state
        return {}; // returning the manipulated state
    }

}, initialState()); // initial state function which returns initial state object
```

`IPageState` is an interface which has various properties on it.

Everything is being compiled and bundled through webpack and runs like a charm, so no issues with the code. We have been using this pattern for the past 2 years and is working fine.

However with the latest Resharper update (version 2017.3), it is now complaining that `handleActions<IPageState, number | string>`

> Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments

I have noticed that Resharper seems to be looking into the file `/node_modules/redux-actions/lib/index.js` to get it's definitions for everything rather than looking into the `/node_modules/@types/redux-actions/index.d.ts` file. So if I delete the `lib` folder, all the Resharper errors go away.

Is there anyway to tell Resharper to just ignore the `lib` folder? I can't just delete it because when doing a fresh install, then the folder will re-appear.

Comment: Have you tried to add this folder to "ReSharper | Options | Code Editing | Third-Party Code" list?

Comment: I have just tried and because the node_modules folder is not part of the solution, I get an error "Some selected folders are not part of solution and were not added."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was noted as a bug within Resharper and has now been fixed. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-467712

If you download the latest version of Resharper the issue is now resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. The only way I've found around it so far is to add a triple slash directive for the type definitions at the top of one of my react components (I put it in app.tsx which is the main react component for my app), e.g.

```
/// <reference path="./../../node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts"/>
```

Adding this to a single file within the source appears to be enough to fix the erroneous R# errors project wide. Not ideal and I have no idea why it should work but it seems to have fixed the problem for me so far.

Comment: Thanks that is a good suggestion to get round this issue just now. It does seem to be a bug within Resharper just now and I have raised the issue with JetBrains, however nothing has come of it yet. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-467712